# Android ListView scrolls with no momentum

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

A `ListView` in my Activity doesn't have scroll momentum - once I put my finger up, the scroll stops. I have another `ScrollView` in the hierarchy, but its `visibility` is set to `gone`.

```
<ListView
                    android:id="@+id/eventsListView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/contentViewSearchBar"
                    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
                    android:listSelector="@color/transparent" />
```

[image: View hierarchy]

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post eventsListViewRefresh code?

Comment: @MariusKaunietis This behavior started before I added this SwipeRefreshLayout so I don't think it would be interfering.

Comment: just a wild thought, did you override the `onTouchEvent()` in your `Activity` and/or `Fragment`?

Comment: @AtifFarrukh oh! Yes. I wanted to make my custom view appear with a swipe and put it on eventsListView.setOnTouchListener. It works with it commented. Now I have to figure out where to put my swipe listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you override the onTouchEvent() in your Activity and/or Fragment? If so check this condition `case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`. This where your "finger up" is detected.

Answer (score 0):

The overscroll code is:

```
666                     if (overScrollBy(0, deltaY, 0, mScrollY, 0, range, 0, mOverscrollDistance, true)
667                             && !hasNestedScrollingParent()) {
668                         // Break our velocity if we hit a scroll barrier.
669                         mVelocityTracker.clear();
```

Your parent view has the ability to scroll. Which means the child doesn't scroll. Throw an error and you'll see that you're in startNestedScroll(int) code. This doesn't care about the visibility, just the existence of the parent.